# Redirect standard output to variable from method with `sys.stdout.write()`

Tags: python, redirect, stdout

I want to use an external library and redirect their output, but the library uses a function represented below as `msg`.

I tested some other stdout methods (all of them are in the minimal example below) and all of them are redirected. I also try to use `contextmanager` without success.

Also if `msg` method takes `file` parameter with `sys.stdout`, the output will be redirected.

```py
import sys
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO
from contextlib import contextmanager


def msg(msg, file=sys.stdout):
    file.write(msg)


def msg2(msg):
    sys.stdout.write(msg)


def print_method(msg):
    print(msg)


stream = StringIO()
write_to_stream = redirect_stdout(stream)
with write_to_stream:
    print("print")
    msg("method\n")
    msg2("method 2\n")
    print_method("print method")
    sys.stdout.write("write\n")

print("\nCaught data:")
print(stream.getvalue())
```

The output of example is:

```
method

Caught data:
print
method not default
method 2
print method
write
```

But I want to get a line with `method` under `Caught data:` line.

Is there an option to redirect method `msg` with the `file` default parameter too?

Comment: Can you elaborate it more , like I am not able to get what you want ?

Comment: I added the output of a minimal example. Is there anything else that I can add? I'm not sure what is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force redirection of all output to stdout to a file object, you can override `sys.stdout` directly with the desired file object:

```
sys.stdout = stream
```

To make the override temporary, however, you can use `unittest.mock.patch` as a context manager:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
from unittest.mock import patch

stream = StringIO()

with patch('sys.stdout', stream):
    print('foo')
    sys.stdout.write('bar')

print('Captured output:', stream.getvalue(), sep='\n')
```

This outputs:

```
Captured output:
foo
bar
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/JealousKnownScience

Comment: I test it and the method `def msg(msg, file=sys.stdout):` still prints to stdout for me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I see. When the function `msg` is defined, the original `sys.stdout` is stored as the default argument for `file` and not affected by a later patch. You can put the function definition in a `patch` context manager to mitigate this issue. Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/AllProfuseVerification

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I must add an import of the library to the `patch` context.